# Angular5 Using HttpCIientModule and interfaces

Tags: angular, http, interface, httpclient

I am learning about the new httpclientmodule and i want ta add an interface to the response. here is my code:

```
interface TestResponse {
  accessToken: string;
  accessExpiration: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class testService {


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }


  getData(pageNumber): Observable<TestResponse> {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('page', pageNumber);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get<TestResponse>(environment.apiUrl + "test", { params: params,  headers: headers});
  }

}
```

But whatever I fill in the interface the response is always correct even when it does not apply to my interface am I doing something wrong?

thx a lot

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong (in that regard). The client doesn't validate that the response actually implements the interface. And it can't possibly do that, since interfaces don't even exist at runtime, but only at compile-time. What you're doing wrong however is that you specify a content type for a GET request although GET requests don't have any content. And even for other requests, JSON is the default content type, automatically set by HttpCLient if you send an object as the body.

Comment: You mean whatever is returned from the `get()` request, the response is always correct? Yes, this is how it works. `Ts` does compile-time checks, whatever is assigned during runtime is not checked. During runtime, you can even return an `integer` instead of an Object and you will not see any errors other than runtime errors if any

Comment: @xyz  Why should we use interface then the response is not really checked by the interface?

Comment: @JBNizet Why should we use interface then the response is not really checked by the interface?

Comment: To tell the compiler that the response will be of type TestResponse, in order to be able to return an Observable<TestResponse> rather than an Observable<any>, which would make it really hard for the callers of the service method to know what to expect as a response.

Comment: @JBNizet also if i dont specify a contenttype i get an 415 error

Comment: Then you have a serious problem on the server. Again, the content can't possibly have a type since there's no content at all.

Comment: @JBNizet what do you mean by no content at all i get an response from the get call that is the content right? do you have teams or skype for further talk?

Comment: The content type header you set on the client is the content type of the **request**. A GET **request** doesn't have any content. The response has a content, but its type is set by the **server**, since it's the server which decides what to send as a response.

Comment: @JBNizet thx for the explanation i get it !!